# notepad++ regex find and replace spaces between brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

In notepad++, want to change this:

```
    [City tier] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Counting unit] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
```

to this:

```
    [City_tier] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Counting_unit] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
```

I have used [\w+(\s)\w+] to locate these two records, but when i use \1_ in replace, i got

```
     _ [nvarchar](max) NULL,
     _ [nvarchar](max) NULL,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this PCRE regex for search:

```
((?:\[|(?!^)\G)[^]\s]*)\s
```

and replace with:

```
$1_
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UsHZSV/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group

    - `\[`: Match a `[`
    - `|`: OR
    - `(?!^)\G`: Start matching again from end of the previous match
  - `)`: End non-capture group
  - `[^]\s]*`: Match 0 or more any characters that are not whitespace and not a `]`
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `\s`: Match a whitespace

Comment: Can we not do it with just `((?:\[)[^]\s]*)\s`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CTZzzZ/1)

Comment: Actually that won't work if there are multiple spaces within `[...]` like `[City main tier]`

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ supports `\G` and `\K` which allows you to use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^][\s]+\K\s+
```

This needs to be replaced by an underscore, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/sS0p6s/1).

---

This boils down to

```
(?:           # non-capturing group (?:...)
    \G(?!\A)  # match after the last match but not at the very start
    |         # or
    \[        # a "[" literally
 )           
 [^][\s]+\K   # not "]" nor "[" nor spaces, \K -> "forget everything on the left"
 \s+          # whitespace characters
```

Effectively, this construct only matches whitespaces within square brackets.